# Почему скрип суммирует числовые значения в ячейке как строку, а не как число?

Tags: javascript, google-spreadsheet

Функции MainFunc() суммируют и вычитает значения ячеек, которые возвращает функция SecondsToHours(). В ячейке (4,5) на листа "Main" должно (по идее) суммироваться заначение taskTotalTime на величину minesTime. Проблема в том, что значение суммируется не как число, а как строка. То есть 0.19 + 0.19 = 0.190.19
Ячейка на листе отформатирована как число (#0,000.00). Самое забавное, что в соседней ячейке (4,6), где та же переменная minesTime вычитается из числа, всё присходит нормально - число каждый раз уменьшается на 0.19.

Что здесь не так?

```js
function MainFunc() {
  var ssMain = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Main")
  var minesTime = SecondsToHours(684)
  
  // здесь всё нормально: вычитает как число
  var taskTimeRamaining = ssMain.getRange(i, 6).getValue();
  taskTimeRamaining -= minesTime;
  ssMain.getRange(4, 6).setValue(taskTimeRamaining);
  
  // а здесь почему-то суммирует как строку
  var taskTotalTime = ssMain.getRange(i, 5).getValue();
  taskTotalTime += minesTime;
  ssMain.getRange(4, 5).setValue(taskTotalTime);
  
  }

function SecondsToHours(s) {
  var h = s/3600;
  h = h.toFixed(2);
  return h;
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что операция сложения строк определена, а операция вычитания - нет.

```js
var v1 = "2";

console.log(10 + v1);
console.log(10 - v1);
console.log(10 + +v1);
```